# System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteException: SQLite error no such table error

Tags: c#, sqlite, database-connection

I am trying to run some unit testing on a solution in VS 2010 and am trying to use SQLite as my database.  The problem is I get the following error:

"Test method AECI.Clio.RecordableIncidentRate_Test.TestClass.QueryDataTest threw exception: 
System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteException: SQLite error
no such table: dbo.vDimIncident"

I have used my SQLBrowser to double check that my table is there.  I even tried changing the name of the table from vDimIncident to dbo.vDimIncident to no avail.

I am unsure of what I am doing wrong.  Here is my error trace:

```
System.Data.SQLite.SQLite3.Prepare(SQLiteConnection cnn, String strSql, SQLiteStatement previous, UInt32 timeoutMS, String& strRemain)
System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteCommand.BuildNextCommand()
System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteCommand.GetStatement(Int32 index)
System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteDataReader.NextResult()
System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteDataReader..ctor(SQLiteCommand cmd, CommandBehavior behave)
System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
System.Data.Common.DbCommand.ExecuteReader()
System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider.Execute(Expression query, QueryInfo queryInfo, IObjectReaderFactory factory, Object[] parentArgs, Object[] userArgs, ICompiledSubQuery[] subQueries, Object lastResult)
System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider.ExecuteAll(Expression query, QueryInfo[] queryInfos, IObjectReaderFactory factory, Object[] userArguments, ICompiledSubQuery[] subQueries)
System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider.System.Data.Linq.Provider.IProvider.Execute(Expression query)
System.Data.Linq.DataQuery`1.System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>.GetEnumerator()
System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
AECI.Clio.RecordableIncidentRate.Harvester.QueryData(HarvestTargetTimeRangeUTC ranges) in C:\tfsprod\AECI.Clio.RecordableIncidentRate\Harvester.cs: line 43
AECI.Clio.RecordableIncidentRate_Test.TestClass.HarvesterHandle.QueryDataTest(HarvestTargetTimeRangeUTC ranges) in C:\tfsprod\AECI.Clio.RecordableIncidentRate_Test\TestClass.cs: line 167
AECI.Clio.RecordableIncidentRate_Test.TestClass.QueryDataTest() in C:\tfsprod\AECI.Clio.RecordableIncidentRate_Test\TestClass.cs: line 54
```

I'm not sure if this would have anything to do with anything but here is my connection string:

```
public void ConfigureHarvester(System.Configuration.Configuration configuration)
{
    context = new DataClassesDataContext(new System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteConnection(@"Data Source= C:\tfsprod\C#SQLite\Community.CsharpSqlite.shell\bin\Debug\test.db"));

}
```

Comment: Did you double check that you are loading good db file (path check)?

Comment: @cichy - Yes, the path is good and the db file can be opened in the the SQLite Database browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.  I had to go to the dbml file, then to the properties of the data class and remove "dbo." from in front of my table name.  I don't know if that is thee proper way of doing it but it works.